# Create Unique record in Neo4j regardless of identifier label

Tags: neo4j

I would like to create a set of three nodes, each set have a different label:

```
Create (n: label1 {email:"123@mail.com"})
Create (n: label2 {email:"456@mail.com"})
Create (n: label3 {email:"789@mail.com"})
```

where the email is unique across all nodes.

```
  Create Constraint On (n:label {email:"123@mail.com"}) Assert n.email IS Unique
```

Only create uniqueness for each label/email combination. Can anyone say if there is a way to get the email unique across all nodes.

Correction to constraint query:

```
Create Constraint On (n:label) Assert n.email IS Unique
```

the one above is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a secondary label on all nodes which have an email property, and set the constraint on that one:

```
CREATE (n:label1:WithEmail {email:"123@mail.com"})
```

and

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:WithEmail) ASSERT n.email IS UNIQUE
```

Comment: Great..I will test it. I have a follow up question! Is the CREATE CONSTRAINT ON a one time run or I have to run it for each node created?

Comment: You only need set it up once, preferably before creating any node, or you won't be able to guarantee unicity.

Comment: as I suspected your answer only move the ball down the road. I can still create duplicate records if I use no label or one different from the three used in my CREATE query. so "CREATE (user:label4 {email:"duplicate"}) will create a duplicate node

Comment: Like I said, you need to set the secondary label on all nodes, i.e. create them all with your main label and the extra one directly. The constraint is on the `WithEmail` label in my example, it obviously won't apply if the node doesn't have that label.